# No audio for mp4 files in Quicktime and ITunes but works for VLC

Tags: macbook-pro, macos, mojave, vlc

I have some movies in mp4 format. They work perfectly on VLC (audio and video) but not with QuickTime and iTunes. I can only watch the video but without audio!
I have a MacBook Air 2017.

Comment: And what codec was used in the MP4 file to encode the audio?

Answer (score 3):

MP4 is a container format,the audio codec format could be aac mp3 ac3,etc.

iTunes and QuickTime can’t support all those codecs.You can use mediainfo to check the exact audio codec format.

You can see the link below
[QuickTime compatible and non-compatible formats](https://www.wondershare.com/quicktime/quicktime-format.html#part1)
[Codecs supported by MP4 container](http://mp4ra.org/#/codecs)

TL;DR according to my experience,probably AC3 DTS opus.
Although they are popular formats, quicktime does not support.

Comment: Is there a list of codecs that QuickTime *does* support so someone can follow these instructions to work out whether this is the issue?

Comment: @grg I updated my answer,but I didn't find the official article from Apple.

Comment: AC3 audio is supported by QuickTime, so it's not that.

Answer (score 1):

I just had this issue converting mkv to mp4 so that itunes would play it. I need this so that I can stream the video to my apple TV HD box.

It would play the audio of the mp4 in VLC or windows media player but itunes stubbornly refused to play the audio.

Here is the solution:

When converting you pick:
Video - H.264 + MP3

> open conversion settings, go to audio tab
> uncheck "keep original audio track" and pick "MPEG 4 Audio (AAC)"

Comment: Thanks! Selecting "MPEG 4 Audio (AAC)" worked for me!